# Angular6 - Jasmin karma unit test Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: unit-testing, angular6, karma-jasmine

My ngOnInit() code is the following

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.isProjectEdit = this._sharedData.isProjectEdit;
  if (this.isProjectEdit) {
    this.projectModel.projectName = this._sharedData.projectDet;
    this.projectModel.projectDescription = this._sharedData.projectDesc;
  } else if (!this.isProjectEdit) {
    this.projectModel.projectName = "";
    this.projectModel.projectDescription = "";
  }
}
```

I have created unit test code for the above code.

```
it("Should eveluate ngOninit", () => {
    fixture.componentInstance.isProjectEdit=false;
    fixture.componentInstance.projectModel = {
      projectName: "Test",
      projectId: 0,
      projectVisualization: false,
      projectDescription: "Test"
    };
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect( fixture.componentInstance.isProjectEdit).toBe(false);
  });
```

Im getting an error "Cannot read property 'isProjectEdit' of undefined" on running the test.

Comment: Looks like _sharedData is undefined